# Input is not being focused

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in which the inputs of its last column the user is able to type a quantity of money. This quantity is evaluated and if it is not ok an `alert()` message appears, the input `val()` is set to $0,00 and this same input SHOULD be focused, but it seems the `focus()` function does not work.

The code seems to me correct and when I debug with firebug sometimes works others don't. When I type on firebug console `$("ID").focus()` it works fine. I was wondering if there's such a person in the world who could help me with this problem!

```
$('#table [type=text]').val('$ 0,00').keyup(function () {
    amf2005_BecameCurrency(this, 20);
}).blur(function () {
    if (!validate($(this).val())) {
        $(this).val('0,00');
        $(this).focus();
    }
    amf2005_BecameCurrency(this, 20);
    $(this).val("$ " + this.value);
});
```

Comment: Add an `autofocus` attribute if you want to focus the input on pageload, or chain on `trigger('focus')`. What you have does not focus the input until it is blurred.

Comment: first things first: cache your jquery objects! `var button = $(this);`

Comment: A little too quick on the trigger. Good catch mate.

Comment: maybe the `.blur()` and `.focus()` are fighting one another? The next text input will be blurred as the the 1st is focused causing it to be validated, which will fail and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This is an educated guess!

In the code you provided, you are calling the "focus" event inside the handler for the "blur" event.  I'm not sure that this is allowed, but there is a simple way to see.

Try replacing `$(this).focus()` with `setTimeout(function() { $(this).focus(); }, 0)`

Using the setTimeout function with a delay of zero should make the browser move the focus right away, but the code will no longer be executed in the context of the blur handler.

Also, you mentioned the alert function.  FYI, there are libraries like jQuery UI that provide functions to draw stylized dialogs as part of the page.  These are considered superior to using the alert function.

Comment: Hi, @Daniel Allen Langdon, I have already tried this approach of using setTimeout(), but unfortunatelly it did not work. But thanks for the help. When I solve this issue, I will let you guys know!